# Ubuntu18.04 ProtonDB, I can't run Among Us (file Among Us.exe not found?)

Tags: 18.04, steam

I have been having some trouble with Steam ProtonDB. I can't lauch the game "Among Us", which is in an Ext Partition in a secondary HDD unit, which is permanently mounted in the folder "media/storage". I have a NVIDIA 2060 graphic card and have my drivers updated. My Ubuntu version is 18.04.
I had run

```
$steam
```

And I can see the log of everything I do in steam. When I launch that particular game (other games like Stardew Valley and Ultimate Chiken Horse work fine) I get the following wall of text. Any ideas on how can I get it working?:

```
Opted-in Controller Mask for AppId 0: 0
Opted-in Controller Mask for AppId 0: 0
Opted-in Controller Mask for AppId 0: 0
[945360]Non-Steam Controller Configs Enabled: 1
GameAction [AppID 945360, ActionID 9] : LaunchApp changed task to ProcessingInstallScript with ""
GameAction [AppID 945360, ActionID 9] : LaunchApp changed task to SiteLicenseSeatCheckout with ""
GameAction [AppID 945360, ActionID 9] : LaunchApp changed task to CreatingProcess with ""
GameAction [AppID 945360, ActionID 9] : LaunchApp waiting for user response to CreatingProcess ""
GameAction [AppID 945360, ActionID 9] : LaunchApp continues with user response "CreatingProcess"
Opted-in Controller Mask for AppId 945360: 0
Game update: AppID 945360 "", ProcID 6581, IP 0.0.0.0:0
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/carolinalove/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
Starting app 945360
>>> Adding process 6581 for game ID 945360
GameAction [AppID 945360, ActionID 9] : LaunchApp changed task to WaitingGameWindow with ""
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/carolinalove/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
GameAction [AppID 945360, ActionID 9] : LaunchApp changed task to Completed with ""
>>> Adding process 6582 for game ID 945360
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/carolinalove/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/carolinalove/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/carolinalove/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
>>> Adding process 6583 for game ID 945360
>>> Adding process 6584 for game ID 945360
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/carolinalove/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/carolinalove/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
>>> Adding process 6585 for game ID 945360
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/carolinalove/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/carolinalove/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
>>> Adding process 6586 for game ID 945360
>>> Adding process 6587 for game ID 945360
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/carolinalove/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgiognomeproxy.so: undefined symbol: g_task_new
Failed to load module: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgiognomeproxy.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gvfs/libgvfscommon.so: undefined symbol: g_task_new
Failed to load module: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgvfsdbus.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgiognutls.so: undefined symbol: g_task_get_source_tag
Failed to load module: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgiognutls.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gvfs/libgvfscommon.so: undefined symbol: g_task_new
Failed to load module: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgioremote-volume-monitor.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgiolibproxy.so: undefined symbol: g_task_set_task_data
Failed to load module: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgiolibproxy.so
>>> Adding process 6588 for game ID 945360
>>> Adding process 6589 for game ID 945360
pressure-vessel-locale-gen: No locales need to be generated
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/carolinalove/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/carolinalove/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
>>> Adding process 6695 for game ID 945360
/media/storage/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Among Us/Among Us.exe: 1: /media/storage/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Among Us/Among Us.exe: MZ����@��: not found
/media/storage/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Among Us/Among Us.exe: 2: /media/storage/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Among Us/Among Us.exe: /media/storage/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Among: not found
/media/storage/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Among Us/Among Us.exe: 2: /media/storage/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Among Us/Among Us.exe: e�}yd}ef}ydxev}yd: not found
/media/storage/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Among Us/Among Us.exe: 2: /media/storage/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Among Us/Among Us.exe: : not found
/media/storage/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Among Us/Among Us.exe: 2: /media/storage/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Among Us/Among Us.exe: }ee}yd: not found
/media/storage/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Among Us/Among Us.exe: 2: /media/storage/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Among Us/Among Us.exe: eP}yd: not found
/media/storage/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Among Us/Among Us.exe: 2: /media/storage/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Among Us/Among Us.exe: ev}yd�yeu}yd��du}yd�{eu}ydRicht}ydPEL: not found
/media/storage/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Among Us/Among Us.exe: 2: /media/storage/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Among Us/Among Us.exe: zef}yd�xew}ydt}xd:}yd�: not found
/media/storage/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Among Us/Among Us.exe: 2: /media/storage/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Among Us/Among Us.exe: E: not found
/media/storage/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Among Us/Among Us.exe: 1: /media/storage/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Among Us/Among Us.exe: .rdata: not found
/media/storage/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Among Us/Among Us.exe: 1: /media/storage/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Among Us/Among Us.exe: t=pu�=�A���=�A��=�A�}��E��E�|2jX3�S���[�]܉�E��s��S
                                                                                                 �]��: not found�]�_^�tf�
/media/storage/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Among Us/Among Us.exe: 1: /media/storage/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Among Us/Among Us.exe: cannot open +A3�: No such file
/media/storage/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Among Us/Among Us.exe: 1: /media/storage/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Among Us/Among Us.exe: �@^]�U��VhP�@hH�@hP�@j�����������t�u���u
                                                                                  ���@���
                                                                                         �u
                                                                                           ��T�@^]ùP+A�: not found
/media/storage/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Among Us/Among Us.exe: 1: /media/storage/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Among Us/Among Us.exe: �V�5: not found
/media/storage/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Among Us/Among Us.exe: 1: /media/storage/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Among Us/Among Us.exe: cannot open ��: No such file
/media/storage/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Among Us/Among Us.exe: 1: /media/storage/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Among Us/Among Us.exe: �u�^�U���uV�0+A�>t�>��6�h�@�&����<+Au�^]á A�P+A����U��SVWUj���U�h�P(R�P$R��]�D�T$���SVW�D$UPj�h1$@d�5� A3�P�D$d��D$(��p
                                                                    ���t:�|$,�t;t$,v-�4v�
                                                                                          ��L$
                                                                                              �H
                                                                                                �|�u�y1$@u�Q�eL$d�
          �R
            9u�ÍISQ�0 A��ISQ�0 A�L$
                                    ��C�k
                                          UQPXY]Y[������WV�t$�L$�|$
                                                                      �����;�;����� �����s�% A�����%�As: File name too long
/media/storage/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Among Us/Among Us.exe: 1: /media/storage/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Among Us/Among Us.exe: �o~p��O�W: not found
/media/storage/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Among Us/Among Us.exe: 1: /media/storage/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Among Us/Among Us.exe: fo~pfg@foPfw: not found
/media/storage/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Among Us/Among Us.exe: 14: /media/storage/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Among Us/Among Us.exe: _�
                                          � ]�@
�@���H<@�   �
T
 @.text�� t=pt=Pt=fGp�����������u���% As>fn�fp��� r��G�� �� �� s���tb�|���G�D$�����t�G����u��������������t ��$����G��������u��D$���������SVW�T$�D$�L$URPQQhp@d�5� A3ĉDd�%�D/media/storage/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Among Us/Among Us.exe��L$,3�p
                                                                             ���t;�T���t;�v.�4v�\��
                                                                                                    �H
 �{u�h���������d���_^[ËL$�A�t3�D�3������U�h�p
                                                       �p�p�>�����
                                                                    ]�D�T$��Ë�U�t赃��L�)�q�q�q(������
      ]�UVWS��3�3�3�3�3���[_^]Ð������j�'3�3�3�3�3����IU��SVWjRh) @Q�<�@_^[]Ë�U�lRQ�t$�������
                                                                                                ]U��@  A�Y��VW�+A3�jh�W�<��h� @���  AY���u2��h�*AP�?YY��u����á  A���tP���
,+A����u�_�^�U��QSVW�顋��0+A�0�E���tr۰��2�_^�V�5,+A��t k�W���*AW�P�@�
                                         ������}��X�@jS�p�@����uP�@�@��Wu5jh��@S�i��
                                                                                       ��t!jh�@S�U��
                                                                                                    �VVS�p�@���3���u
�M�������M��Ƈ��tV�h�@��u��;}
                                  �V���3�_^[�Ë���U���W�<�<+A�� A�ʃ�3��ʃ��u3��D��t���<V�u�u����YY��t�u
V�����Y����l�@����t
           j������Y�3�^_]�U��Vh�@h�@h�@j�w���������t�����@��^]�^]�%X�@U��Vh,�@h$�@h,�@j�<����������t
      ����@����d�@^]�U��Vh<�@h4�@h<�@j���������u
                                                     ���t
                                                         ����@����(@�p(@x(@�(@�(@�D$
                                                                                      ^_Ð�F�G�D$
                                                                                                  ^_ÍI�F�G�F�G�D$
                ^_Ð�F�G�F�G�F�G�D$
                                        ^_���tINO����u����rh����o�oN�oV �o^0�of@�onP�ov�p���������u��� r#�� �� �o�oN��O�� ������u�������t��������������u���t��������u��D$
                                                                                    ^_����̋ƃ������у���tf��$��fofoNfoV fo^0ffOfW f_0fof@fonPfovfp������Ju���t_������t!���o�oN��O�v � Ju���t0����t��������u��ȃ�t��FGIu���$�I�D$
���v�Hu�Y�����������������U����SQ�E���+�+�Q�‹ȃ�t    ��FGIu���t
                                        ��
                                          �E��U�u�M�m��-���VW��_^��]�MU����u�Q�
                                                                                    ���]Y[��
                                                                                            h@A�8������tt�8csm�ul�xuf�x �t�x!�t �x�uK�H��tD�Q��t�e�R�p�I�E������3�8E
                                                                                  ����t�@��t�Q�Y_^[�Ëe����U����U
                  ]�������WV�t$�L$�|$
                                       �����;�;����� �����s�% A�����%�As: File name too long
/media/storage/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Among Us/Among Us.exe: 15: /media/storage/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Among Us/Among Us.exe: �t: not found
/media/storage/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Among Us/Among Us.exe: 15: /media/storage/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Among Us/Among Us.exe: E������f���ǅ�����u
                                                             �Ej^��3��E���f: not found
/media/storage/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Among Us/Among Us.exe: 15: /media/storage/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Among Us/Among Us.exe: �u��C�f: not found
/media/storage/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Among Us/Among Us.exe: 15: /media/storage/SteamLibrary/s�E��e����E����}��tK��tf�2������f��t,�}�ujXf;�u*��u#�E���tj�A_f98u���
                                            f: not found
/media/storage/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Among Us/Among Us.exe: 15: /media/storage/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Among Us/Among Us.exe: E�t: not found
/media/storage/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Among Us/Among Us.exe: 15: /media/storage/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Among Us/Among Us.exe: �E_^���]Ë�U��V������?r3��7����M
                                                                        3��u: not found
/media/storage/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Among Us/Among Us.exe: 15: /media/storage/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Among Us/Among Us.exe: �s��M������: not found
/media/storage/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Among Us/Among Us.exe: 15: /media/storage/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Among Us/Among Us.exe: �vލjP�=j������
                                                         ��^]Ë�U��]������=�-At3��VW�w����u����$V�*Y��u����
      ��-A3���-Aj�=YV�6Y��_^Ë�U����
                                     S�3��E���VW���f��t3j=��[f;�tB�΍yf���f;E�u�+����4N�����f��uՋ�BjP�v��YY������}�f��t|�Ћˍqf���f;E�u�+���j=�AY�E�f;�t8jP�2��YY��t7S�u�V�Y��
                                                                                        ��uH�E��0���E�3�P�c�E�Y�C���f��u��W�)3�W�BYY3�P�8Y��_^[��]�3�PPPPP��̋�U��V���t�W���
                                                                               P���Y��u�V��Y_^]Ë�U��Q� A3ŉE�V��W�~��V��@�Y��;�u��M�_3�^������]���U����;�-AtP�y���Y]Ë�U����;�-AtP�^���Y]�hQ8@��-A�{���hl8@��-A�l����5�-A�2����5�-A����YY�������.A��u��-AVj: File name too long
/media/storage/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Among Us/Among Us.exe: 15: /media/storage/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Among Us/Among Us.exe: E�t�}�t
                                               ��tf�������c����u
���[��t�: not found                                                ��3�f�����
/media/storage/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Among Us/Among Us.exe: 15: /media/storage/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Among Us/Among Us.exe: �w: not found
/media/storage/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Among Us/Among Us.exe: 22: /media/storage/SteamLibrary/steamapps/common/Among Us/Among Us.exe: Syntax error: ")" unexpected
>>> Adding process 6696 for game ID 945360
Game removed: AppID 945360 "", ProcID 6581 
Uploaded AppInterfaceStats to Steam
Exiting app 945360
No cached sticky mapping in ActivateActionSet.[2020-09-20 15:52:17] Background update loop checking for update. . .
[2020-09-20 15:52:17] Checking for available updates...
[2020-09-20 15:52:17] Downloading manifest: media4.steampowered.com/client/steam_client_publicbeta_ubuntu12
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1599861500)
[2020-09-20 15:52:17] Download skipped by HTTP 304 Not Modified
[2020-09-20 15:52:17] Nothing to do
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I may have forgotten to add  I have already got it working flawlessly in another ubuntu machine with the same configuration (except it was on the same hard drive). The compatibility layer, as I have already mentioned, is ProtonDB, so I do not know what could be happening right now, since this error message is new to me.

Answer (score 1):

After reading ProtonDB's forums, I have changed my protonDB version to an older one (4.11-13) and now it started.